# What is the best way to access a method in abstract class when the interface does not have it?

Tags: java, interface

Based on the existing architecture written by someone, I need to extend my implementation. Let me explain with a sample code:

```
interface Configuration{
   public String getPID();
   public void display(); 
}

public abstract class BaseConfiguration implements Configuration {
     @Override
     public String getPID(){
          //some code here
     }
     @Override
     public void display(){
          //some code here
     }

     abstract public <T> T clone(Dictionary<String, Object> properties, 
      Class<T> clazz);
}


public class XMLConfiguration extends BaseConfiguration{
    public <T> T clone(Dictionary<String, Object> properties, 
      Class<T> clazz){
      // implementation  
     }
}

public class ConfigurationAdmin
{
     public static Configuration getCondfiguration(){
        return new XMLConfiguration();
     }
}
```

I can understand that it is not possible to call `clone` method from the interface.

```
Configuration conf = ConfigurationAdmin.getConfiguration();
conf.clone(someDictionary, Foo.class) // Gives compilation error
```

What is the best way to call clone method?

Comment: You have to cast to a type that contains the method.

Comment: Add the method to the interface. Boom, done

Comment: *it is not possible to call `clone` method from the interface*, but is it even a part of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it after casting to `BaseConfiguration` if the object instanece passes an `instanceof` check:

```
if (o instanceof BaseConfiguration) {
  ((BaseConfiguration) o).clone(someDictionary, Foo.class);
} else {
   throw new AssertionError("Does not extend BaseConfiguration");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all configurations should be cloneable, just add it to `Configuration`.

If not all - do it something like

```
interface CloneableConfiguration extends Configuration {
    public <T> T clone(Dictionary<String, Object> properties, Class<T> clazz);
}
```

then

```
public class XMLConfiguration extends BaseConfiguration implements CloneableConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

But never use concrete implementations in your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your `Configuration` object. Use an `instanceof` check for safety since the API is out of your hands

```
Configuration conf = ConfigurationAdmin.getConfiguration();
if(conf instanceof BaseConfiguration) {
    BaseConfiguration base = (BaseConfiguration) conf;
    base.clone();
}
else {
    // throw an exception of log an error
}
```